# ¿Cómo puedo enviar datos a firebase en segundo plano?

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Lo que trato es que mi ubicación se mande a cada 60 segundos a firebase, aún así el teléfono esté bloqueado o lo esté usando con otros programas, (estoy trabajando con AsyncTask en Android Studio).

Al principio cuando bloqueo el dispositivo se siguen enviando los datos, esto hasta que pasan unos minutos, donde el proceso AsyncTask sigue ejecutándose pero se dejan de enviar los datos a firebase

***Este es mi Logcat***, en donde se dejo de enviar a firebase en el proceso 10:[image: Este es mi log cat]

***Este es mi codigo:***

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int MY_PERMISIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
DatabaseReference mDataReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    new BackgroundTask().execute();
}

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
                Log.e("Progreso: ", "" + i);
                obtenerDatos(i); //El metodo "obtenerDatos" es en donde obtengo y envio la ubicacion

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return "Terminamos la tarea";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ser termino de ejecutar la tarea en segundo plano", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Finalizado: ", "" + s);
    }
}

private void obtenerDatos(int nodo) {

    new BackgroundTask().execute();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        return;
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) ;
                    {
                        Log.e("Latitud: ", location.getLatitude() + "Longitud: " + location.getLongitude());

                        double longitud = location.getLongitude();
                        double latitud = location.getLatitude();

                        SimpleDateFormat formatFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MM 'de' yyyy 'a las 'HH':'mm", new Locale("es", "GUA"));
                        Date fecha = new Date();
                        String fechaFormateada = formatFecha.format(fecha);

                        //Guardamos en firebase los datos
                        //Map<String, Object> latlang = new HashMap<>();
                        //latlang.put("Latitud" ,location.getLatitude());
                        //latlang.put("Longitud" ,location.getLongitude());
                        String ubicacion = latitud + "," + longitud;
                        //push es para que genere si id automaticamente
                        //mDataReference.child("Imagenes").child(String.valueOf(nodo)).setValue(ubicacion);
                        mDataReference.child("Imagenes").child(String.valueOf(fechaFormateada)).setValue(ubicacion).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Log.e("se subio el dato: ", String.valueOf(nodo));
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.e("no se subio el dato: ", String.valueOf(nodo));
                            }
                        });


                    }
                }

            });
    return;
}
```

} ´

***Estos son mis permiso en el Manifest:***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un Worker Thread.
A mi me funcionó. Te muestro como lo hice:

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true){
                IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
                Intent batteryStatus = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
                int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                float batteryPct = level / (float) scale;
                float p = batteryPct * 100;
                Map<String, Object> hopperUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                hopperUpdates.put("Porcentaje", p);
                reference.child("App").setValue(hopperUpdates);
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```